# Handling WSDL through Java

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I am new to this, I have a large WSDL which contains many request which I am able to send and receive response from SOAPUI, now I am trying to handle same from java code. Are there any API/JAR's available which can read this WSDL XML files and send some specific.

PS : XML is too large to post here

Please comment if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Comment: Look at this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html

Comment: @canpan14 , if you open this WSDL ,"http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx" you'll be able to see a single xml file handling multiple request, from the SOAP UI we can select on which request to fire , i want to handle similar kind of mechanism using java.

Comment: @NullPointerException Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use any XML parser to read the XML file and like javax.xml , using which we can read specific tags using the getElementsByTagName method and read for specific tags as well as data/attributes associated with that tags.